# Nest components from an array

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I made an hoc withContainer wrapping a component with the provider of a container :

```
const withContainer = Container => Component => _ =>
<Container.Provider>
    <Component />
</Container.Provider>
```

That I use like this :

```
const MyContainer = createContainer(useState) // from unstated-next
const MyProvidedComponent = withContainer(MyContainer)(MyComponent)
```

I would like to make a similar hoc withContainers taking not one container but an array of container:

```
withContainer([C1, C2, C3])(MyComponent) //C1,C2,C3 being containers
```

that would return something like this:

```
<C1.Provider>
  <C2.Provider>
    <C3.Provider>
      <MyComponent />
    </C1.Provider>
  </C2.Provider>
</C3.Provider>
```

Comment: Can you please include what you have tried so far and the problem you can't solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `MyComponent` from the inside out:

```js
var components = [C1, C2, C3]; // or [C1, C2, C3].map(c=>c.Provider) if components are contexts

let result = <MyComponent/>;

for (const Component of components.slice().reverse()) {
    result = (
        <Component>
            {result}
        </Component>
    );    
}
return result;
```

Comment: Thanks, works great (I was actually trying this but I was doing  'let result = MyComponent' and couldn't understand why it was not working)